# Sorting is happening after pagination in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures

I have this Procedure which retrieves data, Sorting it, Then paginate it base on pageNumber and pageSize, But when I execute this procedure and see the result I find that sorting is happening after paginatino and I don't know why
This is the procedure:

```
PROCEDURE SP_SRVS_CLIET_MAP_CODE (
  -- Mapping Data Chnaged By Fatma For CR 105726 25-10-2023
  V_Item          IN     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
  V_MappingCode   IN     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
  V_ClientId      IN     NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
  V_PageSize      IN     NUMBER,
  V_PageNumber    IN     NUMBER,
  CV_1               OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)


AS
      V_SMIT    VARCHAR2 (4000);
      V_Where   VARCHAR2 (4000);
      V_COUNT   NUMBER;
   BEGIN
      V_Where := ' FROM  SERVICE 
                    WHERE 1=1 ';

  IF V_Item IS NOT NULL
  THEN
     V_Where :=
           V_Where
        || ' AND (upper(SERVICE.LOINCCODE||'' ''||SERVICE.NAME) like upper('''
        || V_Item
        || '%'' ) or SERVICE.LOINCCODE ='''
        || V_Item
        || ''
        || '''or upper(SERVICE.NAME) like upper(''%'
        || V_Item
        || '%''))'; -- modified by mohamed abdrabo for task 109039
  END IF;

  IF V_MappingCode IS NOT NULL
  THEN
     V_Where :=
           V_Where
        || ' AND SERVICE.id in  (select HL7SERVICECODES.SERVICEID  from hl7servicecodes  where HL7SERVICECODES.LOINCCODE =  '''
        || V_MappingCode
        || ''')';
  END IF;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(1) ' || V_WHERE INTO V_COUNT;

  V_SMIT :=
        ' 
     SELECT '
     || V_COUNT
     || 'TotalCount,ItemId,
            ItemName,
            ItemType,
            ItemLoincCode,
            ClientMappingCode
       FROM (  SELECT ROWNUM ROW_NUM,
                      SERVICE.id ItemId,
                      SERVICE.name ItemName,
                      SERVICE.SERVICETYPEID ItemType,
                      SERVICE.LOINCCODE ItemLoincCode,';

  IF V_ClientId IS NOT NULL
  THEN
     V_SMIT :=
           V_SMIT
        || '(select hl7servicecodes.LOINCCODE  from hl7servicecodes  where HL7SERVICECODES.CLIENTID = '
        || V_ClientId
        || ' and HL7SERVICECODES.SERVICEID  =
                         SERVICE.id ) ClientMappingCode';
  ELSE
     V_SMIT := V_SMIT || 'NULL  LoincCode';
  END IF;


  V_SMIT :=
        V_SMIT
     || V_Where
     || '
              ORDER BY 
             REGEXP_REPLACE(SERVICE.name, ''[^a-zA-Z0-9]'', ''''),


TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(SERVICE.name, ''\d*'')),
  SERVICE.name)
          WHERE ROW_NUM BETWEEN ( ( '
         || V_PAGENUMBER
         || ' - 1) * '
         || V_PAGESIZE
         || ' ) + 1
                            AND ('
         || V_PAGENUMBER
         || ' * '
         || V_PAGESIZE
         || ')';



              INSERT
                INTO TT_SREACH_RESULT_STMT_LOG (SQL_STMT_LOB,
                                                GENERATE_DATE,
                                                PROCEDURE_NAME)
              VALUES (V_SMIT, SYSDATE, 'INTEGRATION_MAPPING_PKG');
  
              COMMIT;

  OPEN CV_1 FOR V_SMIT;
```

END SP_SRVS_CLIET_MAP_CODE;
I don't know the reason for sorting to happen after pagination despite that I write the sorting logic before the pagination logic, I will be very grateful if somebody helps with it providing an answer

Comment: You really do not need to use dynamic SQL [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xhe6RUZh)

Comment: Or, if you want a string containing bind variables [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RJWPzVZa). Either way, it is less vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: using rownum for pagination is not a good idea, I'd guess that is the cause of the issue - if you're on version 12.1 or higher, have a look at the FETCH clause with offset which is meant for exactly that.